# Selecting and highlight a DataGridView row by checking a checkbox

Tags: powershell, checkbox, datagridview

```psh
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "testform"
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(250,300)
$Form.StartPosition = "Centerscreen"

$button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,100)
$button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,30)
$button.Text = "Click Here"
$button.Add_Click({[void] $form1.ShowDialog()})
$Form.controls.Add($button)

$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,600)
$Form1.Text = "Select row by checking checkbox test"
$dataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$dataGridView.Size=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,500)

$form1.Controls.Add($dataGridView)
$dataGridView.ColumnCount = 2
$dataGridView.ColumnHeadersVisible = $true
$dataGridView.Columns.Insert(0, (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn))
$dataGridView.Columns[0].Name = "select"
$dataGridView.Columns[1].Name = "column1"
$dataGridView.Columns[2].Name = "column2"


$dataGridView.Rows.Add($null, "test", "test2")
$dataGridView.Rows.Add($null, "test3", "test4")

$dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = $false
$dataGridView.AllowUserToDeleteRows = $false
$dataGridView.Columns["column1"].ReadOnly = $true
$dataGridView.Columns["column2"].ReadOnly = $true

[void] $Form.ShowDialog()
```

This simply creates a datagridview with a column of checkboxes, what I want is when a checkbox gets checked, the corresponding row gets selected and highligthed, but I don't know how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To highlight a row, you just need to set the `Selected` property to $true:

```
$dataGridView.Rows[$n].Selected = $true
```

To do it when a checkbox is checked, we'll need to add some code to handle the selection when a corresponding event occurs.

According to the documentation for the [`DataGridView.CellClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick(VS.80).aspx) event (emphasis added):

> For clicks in a **DataGridViewCheckBoxCell**, this event occurs before the
>   check box changes value, so if you do not want to calculate the
>   expected value based on the current value, you will typically handle
>   the **DataGridView.CellValueChanged** event instead. Because that event
>   occurs only when the user-specified value is committed, which
>   typically occurs when focus leaves the cell, **you must also handle the
>   DataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event**. In that handler, if
>   the current cell is a check box cell, call the DataGridView.CommitEdit
>   method and pass in the Commit value.

So, we can simply adapt the example from the documentation page for the [`DataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged(VS.80).aspx) event:

```
$dataGridView.Add_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged({
    param($Sender,$EventArgs)

    if($Sender.IsCurrentCellDirty){
        $Sender.CommitEdit([System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorContexts]::Commit)
    }
})

$dataGridView.Add_CellValueChanged({
    param($Sender,$EventArgs)

    if($EventArgs.ColumnIndex -eq 0){
        $Sender.Rows[$EventArgs.RowIndex].Selected = [bool]$Sender.Rows[$EventArgs.RowIndex].Cells[$EventArgs.ColumnIndex].Value
    }
})
```

If you want to keep multiple rows `Selected`, loop over each row instead:

```
$dataGridView.Add_CellValueChanged({
    param($Sender,$EventArgs)

    if($EventArgs.ColumnIndex -eq 0){
        foreach($RowIndex in 0..($Sender.Rows.Count - 1)){
            $Sender.Rows[$RowIndex].Selected = [bool]$Sender.Rows[$RowIndex].Cells[$EventArgs.ColumnIndex].Value
        }
    }
})

$dataGridView.MultiSelect   = $true
$dataGridView.SelectionMode = [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode]::FullRowSelect
```

[image]

Comment: Is it also possible to keep a row selected when a checkbox is checked?

Comment: I mean when I have 5 rows, check the checkbox in row 1,3,5 those rows are selected. When datagridview opens with the first code, only the first cell is selected. When it opens with the second the entire row is selected without any checkbox checked.

Comment: Can I block all clicks outside the checkbox? I mean that nothing happens when I click inside another cell, or even in the cell with the checkbox but outside the checkbox itself?